# How to get previous record by date in case of no match in a join condition

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have two tables:

dates:

| date |
| --- |
| 2024-01-01 |
| 2024-01-02 |
| 2024-01-03 |
| 2024-01-04 |
| 2024-01-05 |

actual:

| business_date | id |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | 1 |
| 2024-01-02 | 2 |
| 2024-01-04 | 4 |
| 2024-01-05 | 5 |

I want to join these tables on the condition date = business_date, but in the case where there's no match on dates it would get the record of the previous date. So resulting table would look like:

| business_date | id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | 1 | 2024-01-01 |
| 2024-01-02 | 2 | 2024-01-02 |
| 2024-01-02 | 2 | 2024-01-03 |
| 2024-01-04 | 4 | 2024-01-04 |
| 2024-01-05 | 5 | 2024-01-05 |

How would I achieve this?

Comment: What is the data type of columns `date` and `business_date`?

Comment: The type is date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dates
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    actual
  WHERE
    actual.business_date <= dates.date
  ORDER BY
    actual.business_date DESC
  LIMIT
    1
)
  AS actual
```

Or...

```
WITH
  actual_ranged AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    LEAD(business_date, 1, 'infinity')
      OVER (
        ORDER BY business_date
      )
        AS next_business_date
  FROM
    actual
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  actual_ranged AS a
LEFT JOIN
  dates         AS d
    ON  d.date >= a.business_date
    AND d.date <  a.next_business_date
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/tzjjhZJu

Comment: About that `'9999-12-31'`: `±infinity` is a valid `date` value: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/oOAwMr_B), [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-VALUES).

Comment: @IanisDonica Please don't propose using `,` notation, even for lateral joins. It's over thirty years outdated.

Answer (score 0):

An example of [`full outer join`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) with [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) and [`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) window function:  [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zKkmHU1S)

1. It takes all dates from both tables, with the `id` if there's a matching `business_date`.
2. Using `coalesce()`, if it finds that the date doesn't have an `id`, it switches to `lag(id)over w1`, which looks back at the previous date and takes it from that.
3. Does the same thing for `business_date`
4. Note that it treats your criteria strictly: if the previous date is also empty, you'll get a *`null`*.

```
with cte as (select business_date, coalesce(a.date,b.business_date) date, b.id 
             from dates a full outer join business_dates b 
                     on a.date=b.business_date)
select coalesce(business_date,lag(business_date)over w1) as business_date, 
       coalesce(id,lag(id)over w1) as id, 
       date
from cte
window w1 as (order by date)
order by 1;
```

| business_date | id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | 1 | 2024-01-01 |
| 2024-01-02 | 2 | 2024-01-02 |
| 2024-01-02 | 2 | 2024-01-03 |
| 2024-01-04 | 4 | 2024-01-04 |
| 2024-01-05 | 5 | 2024-01-05 |

If that's a gaps-and-islands problem and you'd like `lag()` to skip over nulls until it finds the most recent `id` - making that not just the *previous date* but rather the *most recent with an `id`* - that'd be a `skip nulls` clause that's currently missing from Postgres. Luckily, you can emulate it:

```sql
with cte as (select business_date as bd,coalesce(a.date,b.business_date) d,b.id
             from dates a full outer join business_dates b
                     on a.date=b.business_date)
select (array_agg(bd)filter(where bd is not null)over w1)[1] as business_date,
       (array_agg(id)filter(where id is not null)over w1)[1] as id,
       d as date
from cte
window w1 as (order by d
              desc rows between current row and unbounded following)
order by date;
```

Aggregate functions can be used as window functions, and those have a `filter` clause you can use to skip *`null`* values. The window specification tells it to order them so that the most recent non-*`null`* ends up first in the array, which you then take with `arr[1]`. If you do it often, you can [declare a nicer-looking aggregate function like that](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)).